# incrementing the number of times a list component is clicked?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a list component that lists certain items..

so, if i click on a certain item..i should get the index this way :
var clickedIndex:int = listID.selectedIndex;
but how can i count the number of times the variable clickedIndex has been selected?
so, if a user keeps clicking on the index[0], i want to know how many

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the answer I posted? If it helps solve your problem, you can upvote it by clicking on the ^ arrow and flag it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark icon next to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ideas off the top of my head (I'm assuming your List dataProvider is an ArrayCollection):

1. Modify the Object you're using in the `ArrayCollection` for your list's `dataProvider` to include a `clickCount` property. When an item is selected in the list, increment the `clickCount` property. This will keep the correct number of clicks for each item if your ArrayCollection gets sorted or filtered and the indexes change.
2. Create an `Array` variable to store the click counts for each index in your ArrayCollection. Then you would increment the number the the Array's index that matches the ArrayCollection's selectedIndex.